# How to create custom controls - Prefer to be a normal HTML control instead of server sided

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET development and I want to design a custom control specifically a `Textbox`.

Specification is as follows:

1. Textbox must contains two images, one is on extremely right and another is extremely left.
2. Margin must be fix as per image width
3. If textbox contains some value then left image has to display
4. If textbox is empty left image should be hidden.
5. If textbox receive focus right image should visible. This image will show only when textbox receive focus.
6. Both the images must be above text box only.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you could use a combination of html css and javascript to achieve this I think! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    
    
    $(".text-box").focusin(function(){
      $(this).parent().find('img.msg').show();
    });
    
    $(".text-box").focusout(function(){
      $(this).parent().find('img.msg').hide();
    });
    
    $(".text-box").keyup(function(){
      
      if($(this).val().length>0)
        {
          $(this).parent().find('img.arrow').show();
        }else{
          $(this).parent().find('img.arrow').hide();
        }
      
    });
    
  });
  
  </script>

<style>
  
  .text-box-with-image
  {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
  }
  
  .text-box-with-image input[type=text]
  {
    padding:10px;
      padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
  }
  
  img.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 11px;
    display:none;
}
  img.msg {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 11px;
    display:none;
}
  
  </style>
<div class="text-box-with-image">
  <input class="text-box" type="text">
  <img class="arrow" width="20" height="20" src="http://free-icon-download.com/modules/PDdownloads/images/screenshots/free-icon-download_gradient-blue-arrow-right.png">
  <img class="msg" width="20" height="20" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/appicns/513/appicns_iChat.png">
  </div>
```

Comment: Excellent Puneet!!!... I will try to extend this snippet by adding event handlers, both the image must have click handler to perform some task, once it is done, i will make it plugin for my other projects

Comment: @Manish can you please mark it as Answer if this worked for you? So that others can have the benefit from this answer.